# How do I get systemd to force quit all services on shutdown?

Tags: mount, shutdown, systemd, nfs

I'm running Ubuntu Xenial. Every time I have an NFS mount point mounted and shut down without unmounting it first, I sit and watch systemd's timeout delay extending longer and longer until I have to switch off the machine. But it's not just NFS. It seems like whenever I have any external drive mounted, systemd always hangs. I know this isn't a kernel issue because I haven't upgraded my kernel in a long time (I have an old laptop so I'm stuck with 4.4.0-21). I don't want to dump Ubuntu for Gentoo just to get OpenRC. I love Ubuntu. But this is just driving me nuts.

Any suggestions? (Other than writing a script to unmount everything before shutdown, that is.)